# Golang TLS size too small in TCP communication

Tags: sockets, ssl, encryption, go, tls1.2

I'm trying to setup a tcp socket system with TLS and I have big amount of data in response. I know that the TLS only support 2^14 bytes data, but most of the time I will have more than this, for example there is some part of the code which is return back 170.000 user. I wondering how can I solve this issue with TLS. Of course I want some kind of encryption between the client and server. My current code is basic implementation of the tls.

```
func Handle() {
    conf := TLS()
    listener, err = tls.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:7777", &conf)
    checkError(err)
    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        checkError(err)
        go handleRequest(conn, db)

    }
}

func TLS() tls.Config {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("certs/publickey.cer", "certs/private.key")
    checkError(err)
    tlsConfig := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
    tlsConfig.Time = func() time.Time { return time.Now() }
    tlsConfig.Rand = rand.Reader
    return tlsConfig
}
```

On client side:

```
func withTls() {
    conn, err := tls.Dial(
        "tcp",
        "127.0.0.1:7777",
        &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            ServerName:         "127.0.0.1",
        })
    checkError(err)
    conn.Write([]byte(text))

    var buf [16000]byte
    n, err := conn.Read(buf[0:])
    checkError(err)
    conn.Close()
}
```

What is your offer to use for encryption? Without the TLS on the clientside I got the whole response of the server. The encryption is important because there is communication between servers.

The current speed avarage 15ms/req, I want to keep this speed, which is depend on the data size, but it isn't related to TLS.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Yes a TLS record is limited to 2^14 bytes, but you're not dealing directly with TLS records, you're reading and writing a stream.

Comment: @JimB In this case I misunderstood something, on the clientside I just getting the half of the response when I am using the TLS.

Comment: `Read` returns the data that is available, so you need to Read again until you reach EOF, the correct data size, some message delimiter, etc.

Comment: Ah, ye I got it. I tryed to use this `message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')` and I got all. Now I understand, I just misunderstood how this TLS limit is working.